# substring part of string pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe with the following string column1:

```
{
                    "id": "1",
                    "author": {
                        "self": "https://abc..",
                        "name": "user",
```

I need to substring this column and get value 'user'.
I tired with the following code:

```
df['user']= df["column1"].apply(lambda st: st[st.find("name"):st.find(",")])
```

but I received null. This code works only for elements before first ",". I

Comment: Please can you provide the complete string?

Comment: this is complete string because I needed to split and explode bigger string.

Answer (score 0):

How about `json.loads` to convert the string element to a dict and locate `st['author']['name']` directly? Should work fine if it's not a huge json.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look for the first `:` and `,` *after* "name". `str.find()` allows you to specify which position to start searching from. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find).

So you probably want something like this:

```
df["column1"].apply(lambda st: st[st.find(":", st.find("name"))+1:st.find(",",st.find("name"))].strip()
```